# VPN connects, but cannot not route to internal URL's. How do I debug this?

Tags: networking, vpn, dsl

I have AT&T U-verse DSL at home. I would like to connect to my work's VPN. My VPN client successfully connects; however, when I enter URL's that are internally routed at my work (for example if I typed 'foo' in Chrome, I would be routed to an internal site, not a google search for the word 'foo').

My IT department has been unable to help me on the issue. My question is, where do I start debugging this problem?

Comment: This may not be your issue, but at my last job I had to use `http://foo` when using my VPN.  However, my current one I can just do `foo`.  For what it's worth.

Comment: @nerdwaller thanks for the info. Unfortunately I tried that, but it didn't resolve my issue.